# How QC launches QTP without any script

Tags: qtp

Actually I'm using some older framework to integrate QTP & QC, and of course it worked. But I have noted that there is no script in overall framework to launch the QTP, if its integrated with QC.

So can anyone help me in understanding this, please?

How does QC launch QTP without any code to launch? Is there any HP add-in or functional code works behind to this?

Comment: Usually, QC launches QTP from the test lab, when executing a QTP test contained in a test set. And sure it (QC) contains code for that.

Comment: The core functionality to "know" about QTP tests in QC projects requires the QTP add-in for QC to be installed.

Comment: Can someone let me know whether it's possible to view the code which helps QC to launch QTP? I understood there is some in-built function/code to do this action when we have ALM add-in installed, though wanted to see that particular area. Please share you suggestions!

Comment: Undocumented, and possibly yet unexplored.